# Number of factors in Factor Analysis of Mixed Data with FactoMineR

Tags: pca, factor-analysis, dimensionality-reduction

I'm trying to perform FAMD with FactoMineR because I want to reduce the dimensionality of my data. My data has 378 dimensions and  34K rows. Around 350 of those dimensions are categorical and the rest are continuous.

I'm pretty new with FAMD and techniques like this (PCA, MCA and so on) and my problem comes with the results. I'm getting just 26 factors which explain up to 12% of the variability of my data. I set the ncp option to a much higher value but I still only get these 26 factors.

My doubt is... how can I get more than these 26 factors in order to reduce the dimensionality of my data but reaching a higher variability explanation?

Thanks you so much in advance.

Comment: Why not use fa.poly in the psych package?

Comment: I didn't know this function/package @JaySchylerRaadt but thanks you so much, I'm going to take a look to see if this work!